# Java: GridBagLayout unwanted spacing between adjacent x grids

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I have this GUI

[image]

I have used GridBagLayout for it but I do not know why there is a huge spacing between the Plain Bread checkbox and its corresponding label.

And also, I have tried to increase the spacing along the x-axis only for the button but it has increased along all the components in the x-axis despite resetting the insets (but the spacing between the checkbox between Plain Bread and the label existed before setting the insets for the button).

Here are the codes:

```
 public Bakery(){
    super("Bakery Bread Option");

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    add(panel);

    GridBagConstraints gbc= new GridBagConstraints();

    gbc.insets= new Insets(4,4,4,4);

    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=0;
    panel.add(option_Title, gbc);


    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=1;
    panel.add(check_Plain, gbc);

    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=2;
    panel.add(qty_Plain, gbc);

    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=3;
    panel.add(qty_Brown, gbc);

    gbc.insets= new Insets(0,175,0,0);

    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=4;
    panel.add(calc_Btn, gbc);

    gbc.insets= new Insets(4,4,4,4);

    gbc.gridx=1;
    gbc.gridy=1;
    panel.add(plain_Bread, gbc);


    gbc.gridx=1;
    gbc.gridy=2;
    panel.add(qtyPlainText, gbc);

    gbc.gridx=1;
    gbc.gridy=3;
    panel.add(qtyBrownText, gbc);

    gbc.gridx=2;
    gbc.gridy=1;
    panel.add(check_Brown, gbc);

    gbc.gridx=3;
    gbc.gridy=1;
    panel.add(brown_Bread, gbc);


    calc_Amt calc_Handler= new calc_Amt();
    calc_Btn.addActionListener(calc_Handler);

}
```

**EDIT:**

This is the GUI I intend to achieve:

[image]

Comment: What GUI are you trying to achieve? Please consider posting a valid [mcve] as well. Also, just an aside but your code ignores the weightx, weighty, fill, and anchor GridBagConstraints.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *"What GUI are you trying to achieve?"* Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height. As an aside, a `JCheckBox` can have a `String` to identify the option, so I see no need for a separate `JLabel` identifier. Also since each type of bread seems to have a 'quantity' option, I'd initialise them to 0 (in a `JSpinner`) and lose the check boxes completely.

Comment: Isn’t `GridBagLayout` overkill for what you want? It looks to me like a `BoxLayout` of panels each laid out with a `FlowLayout` would be appropriate.

Comment: *"a picture of the GUI I intend to achieve"* Given the 'resizable' button is not disabled, suggests it can be stretched larger. How is the extra space assigned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> there is a huge spacing between the Plain Bread checkbox and its corresponding label.

Because the components are added to different columns.

The width of a column is determined by the width of the largest component in the column. So the text component determines the width of the column, not the label.

If you want the label/check box to be together, you can create a JPanel and add the two components to the panel. Then add the panel to the gridbaglayout.

Or you could have the two text fields use a columnWidth of 2, which means they will span two columns.

Comment: Just a detail, in this case isn’t it really the Calculate button together with the left inset of 175 that determines the width of column 0?